# Python, SQLite3: How to insert a list of integers into a cell in the table

Tags: python, list, sqlite

I have a list of integers with >2000 items and so I can't split each value into a column of its own due to the 2000 column limit for SQL:

```
a = [1, 0, 0, 1, 0,....]
```

and another str value

```
version = 'dog'
```

How should I be writing the code so that I can input the list, as is, into a single cell, possibly a BLOB type cell?

```
import sqlite3 as sql
con = sql.connect('test.db')
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE tablename(Version TEXT, A BLOB)")
cur.execute("CREATE INDEX Idx_Version ON tablename(Version)")

tuples = tuple([tuple(version, a)])
cur.execute('INSERT INTO tablename VALUES (?, ?)', tuples)
```

I'm fairly new to SQL and would appreciate any help I can get

Comment: Does each value in the list represent the same or different kind of thing? Is it homogeneous, or heterogeneous? Should they have their own row in the table, rather than their own column?

Comment: Are they all `True/False`, `1/0`, `on/off` type values? You could probably encode it as a 2000 bit integer

Comment: The list is always a list of binary values. Here I have shown just one row but there are thousands of rows, and thus, thousands of lists of binary values of identical lengths. Each row of the table contains a list like this. The list has 2048 bits

Comment: I suppose I could create a string of 2048 characters from the list and use that instead, @PeterWood?

Comment: You could uses [`bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#bytes) and store it as a blob.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>list1 = [1, 2, 3]
>>string = ''.join([str(e) for e in list1])

>>string
'123'
```